# How to define independence of vector-valued random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

The independence of $\mathbb R^m$-valued random variables (rv) are defined through cumulative distribution function (cdf) which is straightforward. Could you shed some light on how to generalize the definition of independence of vector-valued rv, for example, rv that values in a Banach space?

Comment: $P(X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(B))=P(X^{-1}(A))P(Y^{-1}(B))$ for all Borel sets $A,B$ in the Banach space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post Kavi Rama Murthy's comment here to remove the question from un-answered list.

> $P\left(X^{-1}(A) \cap Y^{-1}(B)\right)=P\left(X^{-1}(A)\right) P\left(Y^{-1}(B)\right)$ for all Borel sets $A, B$ in the Banach space..